# How to simply draw a line of an equation without marks using pgfplots or otherwise?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have succeeded, sort of, in drawing a set of cost curves for an economics paper based upon this equation: `TC=1750+30x+(x^11)/11^19`.

I have done it by plotting an expression, but it leaves me not with a simple line, but with a line connecting "marks." Is there any way to just draw the line?

Also, if I lower the `ymax` to 150, I get the `Dimensions are Too Big` error.  Likewise, I get the same error when I try to multiply a curve by 1.2 to simulate a 20% sales tax.  The math behind the curves is material, so I would very much like to plot the equation and not a mere facsimile.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{graphicx}               

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=150,
    ymax=200,
    ymin=0]
\plot expression [
    unbounded coords=discard,
    /pgfplots/domain=0:200, 
    /pgfplots/y domain=0:200, 
    samples=50
]       {1750/x+30+x^10/(11^19)};
\plot expression [
    unbounded coords=discard,
    /pgfplots/domain=0:200,
    /pgfplots/y domain=0:200, 
samples=50
]       {750/x+30+x^10/(11^19)};   
\plot expression [
    unbounded coords=discard,
    /pgfplots/domain=0:200,
    /pgfplots/y domain=0:200, 
    samples=50
    ]       {30+x^10/(11^18)};
%\plot expression [
%   red,
%   unbounded coords=discard,
%   /pgfplots/domain=0:200,
%   /pgfplots/y domain=0:250, 
%   samples=50
%]      {1.2*30+1.2*x^10/(11^18))};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Supply \& Demand}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX !

I fixed some of your settings.

Hope this helps

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}      
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      title={Supply \& Demand},
      title style=% set it below
      {
        at={(current axis.south)},
        anchor=north,
        outer sep=.9cm,
      },
      xmin=0,
      xmax=150,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=150,
      % we set your preferences globally
      domain=0:200,
      samples=201,
      unbounded coords=discard,
      % this takes the marks off from the default style
      every axis plot post/.style={mark=none},
    ]
    %I like this syntax better :
    \addplot {1750/x+30+x^10/(11^19)};
    %
    % this shows how to discard the default style (and gets rid of marks)
    \addplot [] {750/x+30+x^10/(11^19)}; 
    %
    % below, we fix the `dimension too large`=`math overflow` warning 
    \addplot +[domain=0:130] {30+x^10/(11^18)}; 
    %
    %\plot expression [
    %   red,
    %   unbounded coords=discard,
    %   /pgfplots/domain=0:200,
    %   /pgfplots/y domain=0:250, 
    %   samples=50
    %]      {1.2*30+1.2*x^10/(11^18))};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```